# Why does jQuery Validation Plugin validate all fields?

Tags: jquery, validation

I had the jQuery Validation plugin running on a few forms but was not entirely happy with it so I moved to a different solution.  After a while I found I needed to return to the plugin but I can not get it working properly.  For some reason, it wants to validate ALL fields in the form, not just those with rules.

Here is the form:

```
<form id="test-form">
    <div class="form-group">
        <label for="firstName">First Name</label>
        <input type="text" name="firstName" id="firstName">
    </div>
    <div class="form-group">
        <label for="lastName">Last Name</label>
        <input type="text" name="lastName" id="lastName">
    </div>
    <input type="submit">
</form>
```

Here is the javascript:

```
    $.validator.setDefaults({
        errorClass: 'help-block',
        errorElement : 'span',
        ignoreTitle : true,
        highlight : function (element, errorClass, validClass) {
            $(element).closest('.form-group').addClass('has-error');
        },
        unhighlight : function (element, errorClass, validClass) {
            $(element).closest('.form-group').removeClass('has-error');
        }
    });

    $('#test-form').validate({
        rules: {
            firstName: {
                required: true
            }
        },
        messages: {
            firstName: {
                required: 'First name is required'
            }
        }
    });
```

When I run it (with both form fields blank) I get the expected error message for firstName, but I also get an error for lastName.  The message simply says 'message'.

I really can't see what I am doing differently this time around, but obviously it must be something!

Answer (score 1):

You need to tell the Validation plugin to [ignore](http://jqueryvalidation.org/validate#ignore) the `lastName` field

```
$('#test-form').validate({
    ignore: '#lastName',
    rules: {
        firstName: {
            required: true
        }
    },
    messages: {
        firstName: {
            required: 'First name is required'
        }
    }
});
```

Comment: Thanks J. Titus.  I can see how that would work, but I'm sure that I didn't have to do this in the past...

Answer (score 0):

Ok, so this came down to a ridiculously random configuration error.  Basically, in my base javascript file I had the following line:

```
$.validator.addMethod('name', function() {}, 'message');
```

I had set out to create a custom validation method and had obviously got distracted.  It seems that this somehow adds the validator to all form elements!